# Java "PatternSyntaxException" Illegal/unsupported escape sequence

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have the following piece of code where i try to get in the pattern matcher a match for strings like ".I 156"   (meaning exactly the characters .I (dot and I) and then a whitespace and then an integer)

```
 while (currLine != null) {
        // Check if current line holds the query ID
        String regexp="\\.\\I\\s\\d";
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regexp);
        Matcher matcher;
        if (pattern.matcher(currLine).matches()) {
            queryBuffer.append(currLine);
            currLine = buffR.readLine();
            queryBuffer.append(".").append(" ").append(currLine);

            QueryListModel.add(iterator, queryBuffer.toString());
            queryBuffer.delete(0, queryBuffer.length());
            iterator++;
        }

        currLine = buffR.readLine();
    }
```

I took the regexp shown above, from regexplanet.com where i tested it and it validated. I checked other sites and validated as well. 
However, in Eclipse console i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 3

\.\I\s\d
   ^
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to escape the `I` letter.

Comment: What is the point of ``\\`` before `I`? (there is none, which is why you are getting this error) Use tools which you understand, if you don't start from reading tutorials about them.

Comment: I inserted the \\ from the copy paste of the online reg exp builder. Obviously i did not know it was not needed, i supposed that the source was true and valid, which was not. Thank you for the answers i already solved it!

Answer (score 0):

```
  String regexp="\\.I\\s\\d");
```

This will match everything that starts with a `.I` and it's fallowed by a number and has exactly 1 white space between them
".I 12132" or ".I 123213213"

Comment: Thank you nice catch with the exactly 1 white space.

Comment: @segconn What catch are you talking about? `\\s{1}` = `\\s`. `{1}` is redundant and should be removed in order not to confuse anyone.

Comment: Done. Since he didn't exactly explained what he wanted, if it didn't worked for him, i was going to tell him to change the number in the brackets :) . This is why i left it there.